# How to import an online CSV file into Java and use each column as a variable?

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I am trying to import a CSV file online which contains 6 fields. I am trying to import from a web link. I am able to download the file and use the file name as well. What I am trying to do is to read the data from the file and output it to my program.
So far I have this:

```
public class Element {
    public static final String CSV_FILE_URL = "http://www.google.com/File.csv"; //Actual URl not published

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(CSV_FILE_URL);
        Scanner input =
                new Scanner(url.openConnection().getInputStream());}
    int number ;
    String symbol;
    String name;
    int group;
    int period;
    double weight;
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be a good idea to not use a Scanner but read the file line based, transform the lines into elements and then work on these like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/File.csv");
        try(InputStream in = url.openStream();
                InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inr)) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                //Best case: no String separation, no ; contained in data items. If not
                //you need some other way to split this
                String[] elements = line.split(";");

                //Deal with that one line 


                //Get next line
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```